# Symfony Twig error Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I try to create OneToMany association in my Creation entity.

**Creation**

```
class Creation
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Categorie", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="creation")
     */
    private $categories;

    // ...
}
```

**CreationType**

```
class CreationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('categories', EntityType::class,  array(
                'class'         => 'App\Entity\Categorie',
                'choice_label'  => 'label',
                'multiple'      => true,
            ));

    }
}
```

Now, I want display my Categories in my twig template :

```
{% for categorie in creation.categories %}
    {{ categorie.label }}
{% endfor %}
```

I have this error, whereas I can display in dump this creation :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined index: creation").

Someone can help ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for help.
In my form, when I use EntityType, I can see all my Categories and choose them. Not with Collection.

->add('categories', CollectionType::class,  array(
                'entry_type'   => CategorieType::class,
            ))

do I use it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

EntityType inside your form is ok. you should just pass `creation` into your twig view, inside your controller.

You probably have a controller section like this:

```
class CreationController
{
    // ...

    public function showAction(Request $request)
    {
        $creation = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Creation::class)->find($request->get('id'));

        return $this->render('creation_show.html.twig', ['creation' => $creation]);
    }

    // ...
}
```

You should pass the `$creation` object as `creation` into your template so that you will be able to use it inside twig template